# python - how do I fix interpolate grid origin issues in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, interpolation, gridding

I have a data set with a small sample size of data. For example:

[image: Data]

My code looks something like this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import Rbf

df=pd.read_csv('test.csv')
df.head()

extent = x_extent = x_min, x_max, y_min, y_max = [df["X"].min()-1000, df["X"].max()+1000, df["Y"].min()-1000, df["Y"].min()+1000]
grid_x, grid_y = np.mgrid[x_min:x_max:100, y_min:y_max:100]
rbfi=Rbf(df["X"], df["Y"], df["Total"])
di=rbfi(grid_x, grid_y)
plt.scatter(grid_x, grid_y, s=10)
plt.figure(figsize=(15,15))
plt.imshow(di.T, origin="lower", extent=extent)
c2 = plt.scatter(df["X"], df["Y"], s=60, c=df["Total"], edgecolor='#ffffff66')
plt.colorbar(c2, shrink=0.6)
plt.show()
```

the result:

[image: data result]

The result is a scatter plot of my points that appear to be in the correct place, but the interpolated grid is not covering the scatter points. So I think this has something to do with my origin not being correct, but I don't know how to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two approaches here, one with a Delaunay triangulation, the other using the Radial Basis Function. Snippet and figure below.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.tri import Triangulation
from scipy.interpolate import Rbf

rng = np.random.default_rng()
X = rng.random(size=(15))
Y = rng.random(size=(15))
Total = rng.random(size=(15))
fig, (ax, bx) = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2, num=0, figsize=(16, 8))
tri = Triangulation(X, Y)
tctrf = ax.tricontourf(tri, Total)
gridY, gridX = np.mgrid[np.amin(Y):np.amax(Y):100 * 1j,
                        np.amin(X):np.amax(X):100 * 1j]
rbfi = Rbf(X, Y, Total, function='linear')
iTotal = rbfi(gridX, gridY)
bx.contourf(gridX, gridY, iTotal)
scat = ax.scatter(X, Y, s=60, c=Total, edgecolor='black')
fig.colorbar(scat, ax=ax)
scat = bx.scatter(X, Y, s=60, c=Total, edgecolor='black')
fig.colorbar(scat, ax=bx)
ax.set_aspect('equal')
bx.set_aspect('equal')
fig.tight_layout()
fig.savefig('so.png')
plt.show()
```

[image]